# Swift - select single radioButton in tableView

Tags: swift, checkbox, radio-button, tableview, sections

I have a tableView, which is expandable. The headerCell has a checkBox, a label and a radioButton. The collapsableCell has a checkBox and a label.

I have used **M13Checkbox** Library to implement the checkBox and the radioButton.

The problem is when I select a radioButton or a checkBox of HeaderViewCell at index 0, then the radioButton/checkBox at index **8,16,24** also get selected. I know it is because of the numberOfSections in tableView property, But then how do I select just single radioButton at a time. 
My requirement is I have to select single radioButton in the tableView and CheckBoxes can have multiple selections for the HeaderCell.

I am badly stuck on this issue. I have googled a lot but nothing worked. Any help or suggestion much appreciated.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return states.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return states[section].cities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (states[indexPath.section].expanded) {
        return 44
    }else{
        return 0.0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerviewcell") as! HeaderView
    var list = states[section]
    headerCell.customInit(titleLabel: list.stateName, section: section, delegate: self)
    return headerCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subcells") as! CollapsibleCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none   
    cell.textLabel?.text = states[indexPath.section].cities[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // works for headers or cell??
}

func toggleHeader(header : HeaderView, section : Int){
    states[section].expanded = !states[section].expanded

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    for i in 0 ..< states[section].cites.count {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is my code for HeaderView. Whenever I select any radioButton, then any random radioButton for other sections also get selected. Upon scrolling the state and section of radioButtons changes. Please help me solve this issue. I am aware it's related to cell reuse property, but I can't solve it.

```
import UIKit
import M13Checkbox

protocol HeaderViewDelegate {
    func toggleHeader(header : HeaderView, section : Int)
}

protocol CustomHeaderDelegate: class {
    func didTapButton(in section: Int, headerView : HeaderView, button : M13Checkbox)  
}

class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

@IBOutlet weak var stateCheckBox: M13Checkbox!    
@IBOutlet weak var stateNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var favouriteState: M13Checkbox!

var delegate : HeaderViewDelegate?
weak var delegateHeader: CustomHeaderDelegate?   
var sectionNumber : Int!
var section : Int!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    stateCheckBox.boxType = .square
    stateCheckBox = .bounce(.fill)

    favouriteState.boxType = .circle
    favouriteState.setMarkType(markType: .radio, animated: true)
    favouriteState.stateChangeAnimation = .bounce(.stroke)
}

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target : self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView)))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder : aDecoder)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target : self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView)))
}

func selectHeaderView(gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let cell = gesture.view as! HeaderView
    delegate?.toggleHeader(header: self, section: cell.section)
}

func customInit(titleLabel : String, section : Int, delegate : HeaderViewDelegate) {
    self.stateNameLabel.text = titleLabel
    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate
}

@IBAction func selectPrimaryCondition(_ sender: M13Checkbox) {
    // get section when favourite state radioButton is selected
    delegateHeader?.didTapButton(in: sectionNumber, headerView : self, button : sender)
}

 override func prepareForReuse() {
    // What do do here…??
} 
}
```

Comment: This is because of reusing of tableview cell, you have check this condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath also,

if selectIndexPath.row == indexPath.row {
        subCell.checkBox.isSelected = true
    }else{
        subCell.checkBox.isSelected = false
    }

Comment: Hi @AustinMichael. `cellForRowAt indexPath`  implements my expandable/collapsible cells. how do I check the condition for HeaderView, since I have to select only single radioButton at a time.

Comment: If it's Headerview, do that in viewForHeaderInSection

Comment: @AustinMichael Yes I understood that, But what do I have to check. I previously tried to check in `viewForHeaderInSection` as well, still no results. It still selects multiple radio buttons as well as radioButtons in other sections get selected.  I am really blank on this.

Comment: What confuses me is: in `tableView:didSelectRowAt:` you first assign `self.selectIndexPath = indexPath`, and later you check `if selectIndexPath.row == indexPath.row` -- but this should always be the case, because you just assigned it to the very same value.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Sorry for late reply. Can you help me solve first problem. With prepareForReuse() method. Why are multiple sections getting selected? How to solve this basic problem I have tried a lot.. :(

Comment: @Bella It would be helpful if you could provide a small compile+runnable Xcode project (uploaded to github or somewhere) that just shows your problem.

Comment: @AndreasOetjenSorry, I could not upload the project due to some restrictions. My problem is when I select radioButton in headerCell at index 0, then radioButtons at section 8, 16 get selected first, and when I scroll the tableView, then radioButton in any random section is getting selected. Please help

Answer (score 0):

TableViews are tricky when saving data without knowing some kind of saved state that can be held in some sort of object class is it can do some weird things such as reuse cells; selecting incorrect cells in your case. I'm guessing that you've created some kind of object for your states and cities. I'd make sure that they're classes and not structs and make sure they have some sort of isTapped `Bool` so you're able to actually save the state for that individual object like so:

```
class CellObject: NSObject {

    var isTapped: Bool

    init(isTapped: Bool) {
        self.isTapped = isTapped
    }
}
```

Instead of just setting your isSelected to true or false inside your `didSelect` method, set THAT cells object `isTapped` to true or false AS WELL as changing the state to whatever you want, i.e change it's background colour to black to show it's selected. When loading your cell inside of your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, check if the cells object `isTapped` is either true of false and set it's state, colours etc. accordingly. This is the barebones of the idea but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I have used **_struct_** for states and cities.